# in ReactJS, how can i filter the rendered result according to an id number passed in the props

Tags: reactjs

I have a Navlink Component that has a catid prop (a number)

```
<NavLink catid={category.id} to={category.route}>
                  <img src={category.img} alt={category.name}/>
                    <p>
                        {category.name}
                    </p>
 </NavLink>
```

so it routes to another component, stateful component, like so :

```
 class ProductListFilter extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state =  {
                ...props,
                cat: props.catid 
            }

        }

render() {
        const { addToCart, removeFromCart, products, cart} = this.props;         

        let filteredProds =  products.filter((item) => (
           item.cat_id === this.state.cat
        ))

        return <div className="products-list row mb-3">
            {
               filteredProds.map((product, index) => (
                    <ProductListItem
                    key={index}
                        product={product}
                        addToCart={addToCart}
                        removeFromCart={removeFromCart}
                        //cart={props.cart}
                        cartItem={cart.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id === product.id)[0]}
                    />

                )
                )}
        </div>
    }
}
```

unfortunately it doesn't work, I dn't get any result. I have to say that every product from the json i fetch has a cat_id set.
Thanks for your help

Comment: unrelated to your question but why are you putting all your props in the component state?

Comment: Sorry, i am an absolute beginner, but effectively it's useless

Comment: can provide an example of the data you are passing? and the code for 'ProductListItem'?

Comment: Ali , if i replace this.state.cat in the filteredProds function by a number, let's say 11, it works and displays all the products that belongs to the category 11

Comment: So this probably means the props you are passing are incorrect

Comment: This is how the navLink component renders 
<a catid="11" href="/boissons"><img src="./categories/menuFooter-boissons.jpg" alt="Boissons"><p>Boissons</p></a>

Comment: Can you show me where and how you are using `ProductListFilter`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208593/discussion-between-ali-almoullim-and-stephane-joos).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your component works as expected given the passed props are correct. You could, however, given that this component does not need a state (stateless), refactor the component into a functional one like so:

```
const ProductListFilter = ({ addToCart, removeFromCart, products, cart, catid }) => {
  let filteredProds = products.filter(item => item.cat_id === catid)
  return (
    <div className="products-list row mb-3">
      {filteredProds.map((product, index) => (
        <ProductListItem
          key={index}
          product={product}
          addToCart={addToCart}
          removeFromCart={removeFromCart}
          //cart={cart}
          cartItem={cart.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id === product.id)[0]}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```